# heroku dns multiple subdomains

Tags: heroku, dns

I redirect `example.com -> www.example.com` using my DNS provider

I have set `hello.example.com to myapp.herokuapp.com`   (CNAME)

and added hello.example.com to my domains list on the heroku app.

Now, what I would like to do then is, redirect

```
www.example.com -> hello.example.com
```

I did this using a CNAME. However, this doesn't work *unless* I add www.example.com to my domains list on the heroku app. But the behavior I want is, www just redirects to hello, and the app gets served from hello---no need to even involve www. This feels like a DNS issue mostly---ideas?

Answer (score 0):

DNS doesn't perform redirects although some DNS providers have added the ability which appears it may. You'll want to do some kind of redirect inside your application using something like rack-redirect (if you're writing a Ruby application). If you weren't using Heroku it's something that your webserver would normally do.

What you essentially want to do is check the domain being requested and if it's not your primary (ie hello.example.com) then you redirect it to hello.example.com

```
MyApp::Application.config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Lock, Rack::Rewrite) do 
 r301 %r{.*}, 'http://hello.example.com$&', :if => Proc.new {|rack_env| 
  rack_env['SERVER_NAME'] != 'hello.example.com' 
 } 
end if Rails.env == 'production'
```